# Adding messages to the answer box to help reduce the number of "not an answer" answers

Tags: discussion, late-answers

Many new users take some time to get used to Stack Exchange community.
As a consequence we get a lot of "not an answer" answers.

It is very likely that these new users will only seek for guidance after they receive feedback from their first "not an answer" post.

What if the **Your Answer** box header had a customized messages for <10 rep users? Like below:

[image]

The message inside the brackets is just one example, but could be improved to be the most informative as possible, maybe also directing to the help center page.

After reaching a certain reputation threshold (like a privilege), the warning message would disappear.

Comment: 15 seems good. Remove it when they gain the privilege to upvote/flag?

Comment: While I'm behind this proposal, the people who already aren't reading the documentation aren't likely to be deterred by another label. After all [users don't read](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/10/treating-user-myopia.html), and eventually we're just begging them to find out what we're about and how we work before participating.

Comment: JoshC 15 sounds good too. @mikeTheLiar, you may be right. But we could try and see what happens :).

Comment: There is nothing difficult to understand about "Your Answer", even for someone unfamiliar with the English language. If someone can't even understand what an "answer" is, I don't think telling them what it *isn't* will be very effective.

Comment: I vote for 50, when they get the comment privilege

Comment: I agree with @JanDvorak That seems like the most useful duration, since that's when they are less likely to 'want' to post NAA's anymore.' That is, assuming we think it's needed or would be useful at all.'

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, I would agree with you if had not seen by myself such amount of "not an answer" answers. You may be correct either, but I think we could give a shot on this and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already a feature that fits your request, a new user is shown the following when selecting the answer text field:

[image]

I'm not sure what the reputation threshold is for this notice, though.

Comment: Thanks. I did not remember about that. mikeTheLiar and  BoltClock's a Unicorn were right in their comment.